# Pedido Não Entra no Magento, Mas no Ambiente do Método de Pagamento Sim!

Tags: magento, pagamento-online

Olá,

Estou enfrentando um problema em minha loja magento, onde quando clientes tentam finalizar o pedido na plataforma e na mesma o pedido não é salvo. Porém não é esse o problema, o que prejudica nesse caso é que no ambiente do método de pagamento que utilizo o pedido se encontra realizado.

Ou seja, no magento pedido não entrou, mas no método de pagamento sim.

Isso está me dando muitas dores de cabeça. Antigamente esse erro se dava por conta de deadlocks e minha base de dados. Mas agora não os possuo mais, alguém ai já passou por essa situação?

A versão do magento utilizada é a 1.7.0.2